tar using --transform flag is replacing symlinks when extracting archive
When I unpack a tar.gz archive using this command on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS:
tar -xvf foo-bar-linux-x64.tar.xz --transform "s:^[^/]*:foo-bar:"

everything is unpacked into a foo-bar folder instead a foo-bar-linux-x64 folder (which is the one by default as encapsulated in the archive),  but I notice that all symbolic links existing in the archive file structure now point to -> foo-bar instead of their respective libraries, e.g. in ./foo-bar/lib/:
libwhatever.so -> foo-bar instead of libwhatever.so -> libwhatever.so.1.2
Why and how to fix this?
Edit:
I also tried:
tar -xvf foo-bar-linux-x64.tar.xz --transform "--transform "s:^[^*/]*/:foo-bar/:"

it works, but it curiously creates two folders: foo-bar-linux-x64 which is empty and foo-bar/ which is apparently OK.
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.34
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.


Have you tried --transform "s:^foo-bar-linux-x64:foo-bar:"?

Indeed, it seems to work. The only "problem" is that I don't know the name of the embedded folder in advance because it's a downloaded file and it may change in time.  What I'm pretty sure is that in the archive file, there is only one embedded folder with all the stuff inside.

How about --transform "s:^[^*/]*/:foo-bar/:", so that you actually match a directory component instead of a regular path in the current directory?

There's also the option of making the foo-bar directory yourself, then doing tar ... --strip-components=1 -C foo-bar .... https://askubuntu.com/a/953763/158442

I update the post after trying your first solution, which works but creates two folders. The second one also works. In both cases, those commands needs a second rmdir or mkdir call after or before in order for them to work correctly. It's OK to me, but maybe some people would be interested in a one-shot tar command.
